# Is it Possible to Disable Feed and Topics for an Object Completely at Profile Level / Page LayOuts

Tags: visualforce, community, administration, partner-communities

I need to display Case object(Detail page) in Portal Page for External users, And i need to Hide the Feed(No More "Show feed / Hide feed ") completely. Is it possible to hide feed in case object rather than creating a new page that display Case details in Portal page. i have created a new page layout with Un-checking "Feed based Layout" but i didnt achieved.Please any one clarify me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to turn off chatter for specific profiles. You can hide it by overriding the view page with a custom Visualforce page and displaying the chatter on the detail conditionally if an internal user or external user. Something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name != 'Community User'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Case.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="true"  />
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'Community User'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Case.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="false"  />
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

If the user follows the record however, chatter updates still show in their news feed.

Comment: Hi CyberJus, Thanks for your Kind reply. I have changed my detail page with this. Its working, Thanks alot!