# How to remove chatter feeds based on the page layout

Tags: leads, chatter-feed-tracking, chatter-feed, feed-based-layout

I have removed the chatter fields by using " feed tracking" option but i want to remove the chatter feeds based on the page layout (feed should be present for one layout , should not be present for another layout) . Is it possible in salesforce ? 
I just cloned an existing layout and didnt check the "Enable feed" check box . But still i am able to see the feed

Answer (score 1):

The Chatter feed is a default component of Salesforce page layouts and is not possible to remove from them using declarative tools.

A Visualforce page can be used to display a page without the feed, but that is the only option available.

This previous [question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83098/is-it-possible-to-disable-feed-and-topics-for-an-object-completely-at-profile-le) covers it.