# How to hide this side bar Collapsible arrow in Case Detail Page for specific Profile(Portal Users)

Tags: profile, configuration, partner-portal, sidebar, user-interface

How to hide this side bar Collapsible arrow(i.e no sidebar) in **Case Detail P**age for specific Profile(Portal Users).

We have an option **Enable Collapsible Sidebar** , **Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages** in User Interface. But it will remove side bar for all the users.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it Possible to Disable Feed and Topics for an Object Completely at Profile Level / Page LayOuts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83098/is-it-possible-to-disable-feed-and-topics-for-an-object-completely-at-profile-le)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question linked in the comment above. From what I can tell, this question is about removing the collapsible sidebar rather than the `hide feed` button. The answer could possibly be the same, but again, I don't feel that the question itself is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

For this Scenario, I have created  new Home Page Layout without any sidebar actions and assigned to the profile. Any how the user is still able to see the arrow, Even if he clicks he cant see anything.(That's OK)